# ASP Repeater get multiple selected row values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, repeater

I have a repeater that is bound with three values, a visible "User Name" and "Business" column and a HiddenField of "UserId". I need to accomplish a couple of things, when I click on a row, I want the row to highlight to a different color. Mulitple rows can be selected. Once I am done selecting rows, I hit the confirm button and I need to work with the hidden field "UserId" in the code behind of these selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a another Hidden Field to the Row as a flag, fill it with whatever data is useful. Then server side you just need to check the hidden field of the row to determine if work needs to be done. You can fill the field Client Side, by use the ClientID in the Javascript Method Property of each row. Hope this helps